# Storybook shows Action logs, but no visual changes are made (React Typescript + Vite)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I'm trying to implement some React components in Storybook.

The components themselves work fine on my app but, although the Actions log shows every change, not visual changes are shown neither on checkboxes (onClick React event), comboboxes (onChange) or textfields (onChange). It only shows the CSS effects (for example when clicking a button).

[Checkbox story example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQpIO.png)

[Checkbox working on the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB5l5.png)

¿Do I also need to copy the whole functionality of each event into the .stories files to make them work?

I have tried to export the events in many ways and adding the events into argTypes, but none of these change the behaviour.